# How to make the classes generated by Entity Framework implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I am using MVVM pattern in WPF to create a program.

I was peacefully implementing INPC on my model classes .... until a few days ago when I decided to use EntityFramework. Now I dont know how I can tell the EntityFramework to implement INPC on the generated entity classes and raise the property changed event every time a property changes.

Other questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132349/implement-inotifypropertychanged-on-generated-entity-framework-classes) simply suggest to implement INPC on ViewModel, but I really want the Model classes to implement INPC to reduce the amount of work.

I am using Model-first approach to generate my model.

Comment: You can change the generated T4 Template for the model to implement INPC. This is quite a long process as there is a lot of things to change (generate the backing fields and Getter / Setter, mainly).

Comment: @SimonBelanger Can you post a link to a walkthrough, tutorial or a example which can show me how to do this using T4 Template? Thx very much for helping.

Comment: This seems like a good start: http://pjgcreations.blogspot.ca/2012/12/enabling-mvvm-inotifiypropertychanged.html

Comment: Oh great! Thx. I will try and report back.

Answer (score 2):

The recent release of Microsoft Prism's "Unity Container" addresses this question straight on with its 'Behaviour Interception' feature.  Using the feature can make any class *BEHAVE* as though it inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged.

The most compelling attraction to the feature is that your EF classes can remain blissfully unaware of what's happening and do not need manual coding modifications in order to work.  As you might expect, there's a performance hit which you have to measure against your requirements.

You can download Prism here. [Prism](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=28950)

There's a walk-through that you SHOULD be able to cut-and-paste into your code here. [Interception Behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660851%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)  You can wire up the code from this walkthrough in your app's start up phase, and Unity will handle the rest...

Having some code all ready is a great advantage because it can get hairy if you haven't worked with Type Injection before, so I recommend the walkthrough.

Comment: Either a class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, or it doesn't. There is no way a class can behave "as though" it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` without actually implementing it, because other libraries test specifically for that interface using `is`/`as`. But if I'm reading it correctly, classes get created dynamically that really do implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: When a given class has been wired up, other classes that do interface testing using "is" or "as" will get a "True" response.  Otherwise you should contact the Unity team and let them know that there's "no way a class can behave as though it..." because they are saying otherwise.

Comment: "without actually implementing it". Like I said, it seems like types get created dynamically that don't just behave as if they implement the interface, they *do* implement the interface.

Comment: What word would you have us use that gives semantic elevation to the one currently used, which is 'behavour'?

Comment: I don't think hvd has an issue with the word "behave". It is with the phrase "as though". With Prism you define an interceptor - such as the NotifyPropertyChangedBehavior class described in your link. Then you use the unity container to retrieve the Model class. It then creates a proxy object that wraps or inherits the original object AND implements the interface.

Comment: Why not provide that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a few lines of code using a NuGet package called [PropertyChanged.Fody](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PropertyChanged.Fody/).  The documentation is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged).  See my CodeProject tip ["Adding INotifyPropertyChanged to Entity Framework Classes"](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/853383/Adding-INotifyPropertyChanged-to-Entity-Framework).