# Binding UI-Element not Refresh by Change value in Itemsource

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, datagrid

i'm new by programming in wpf and c#.
I have a litte problem with an datagrid.
The grid is binding on a EF-Table.

I can see and change all fields and save the changes to the database.
The problem is. When i save the data via context.savechanges to the SQL-Database, the Trigger on the SQL-Server-Table modified some fields in the record.

When is Reload the Entity for the currentItem after the save-command, i can see the modified data in my Entity but not in my UI. 
I must make a datagrid.items.refresh to see the changes. But the refresh is not performant and i loose the current cell position.
I need a way, to push any changes from SQL-Server on the current record on the fly to the UI after change on field in the UI.

Have anybody some ideas?

In an simpel TextBox-Element on a Window, i can use the BindingExpression to push the changes via binding.UpdateTarget. But it's not possible in DatagridTextColumn.

Comment: You can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your entities classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your entity class should implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and raise change notications whenever a data-bound property is set to a new value.

If you are using auto-generated entity classes, you need to modify the template that these are generated from:

[How to get property change notifications with EF 4.x DbContext generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010718/how-to-get-property-change-notifications-with-ef-4-x-dbcontext-generator/12192358#12192358)

Or you can bind to your own wrapper classes that do implement this interface:

[Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on generated Entity Framework classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132349/implement-inotifypropertychanged-on-generated-entity-framework-classes)